# Calling a Parse function in server side

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud, server-side

i'm asking for parsers,
On the server side (cloud code), is there a way to call a function defined in other function ? Function should not be called on the client

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getProfiles", function(request, response) {..})

Parse.Cloud.define("otherFunction', function(request){

//call to getProfiles })
```

Comment: you are going to want to learn to use .then so you don't have to call parse like that. the .then method will create an order for your code and make your code wait for the other code to finish before moving on like it would normally.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with dev policy. I keep in the habit of using `Parse.Cloud.define` as the means of wrapping a function for external invocation, always building and naming them as follows...

```
// this is just a "wrapper" for the simple JS function
Parse.Cloud.define("getProfiles", function(request, response) {
    // the only thing I allow to happen here is:
    // 1) unwrap params...
    var param = request.params.param;
    // 2) call an unwrapped function by the same name (this assumes it returns a promise)
    getProfiles(param).then(function(result) {
        // invoke response success and error
        response.success(result);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});

// always have an unwrapped function named identically
function getProfiles(param) {
    // do some work and (usually) return a promise
}
```

Other functions in the cloud, wrapped or unwrapped, can now call the unwrapped function directly.

Answer (score 1):

[Cloud code documentation](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide) recommends to call defined functions as follows:

You can use `Parse.Cloud.run`.

```
Parse.Cloud.run("getProfiles ", {
    //here you can pass the function request parameters
    userId: user.id
}).then(function(result) {
    //here you will handle the returned results (if function returned response.success())
    console.log(result);
}, function(error) {
    //handle errors if called function returned response.error()
    console.error(error);
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Calling *within* the cloud via Cloud.run() uses extra effort for flattening and unflattening params, building requests and responses, etc.  as well as making the caller-side much more verbose.